# Where do I start learning from for motion planning underactuated robotics?

Tags: motion-planning, path-planning

I am an undergraduate student approaching my final year. I have a final year project which involves planning a trajectory for an underactuated robot that also avoids obstacles.

So far I have come up with the differential equations that govern the robot as well learned about the iLQR which is an unconstrained optimisation technique. Is there a way to add constraints to the control inputs as well as add bounds to the different states?

Answer (score 1):

This website was really helpful for me when learning all about robotics: https://robotacademy.net.au

It has lots of info on motion planning / path planning too.

I guess this isn't a direct answer to your question but for anyone coming here looking for educational resources, this is a good one.